# output token response in callback url page in node

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

Hi I have implemented LINE API module and can successfully redirect to the callback url, however the issue is that it does not output the res.send(token_response) in the callback page. Is there anyway I could render it in the callback page?

This is my code.

```
"use strict";

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const line_login = require("line-login");

const login = new line_login({
    channel_id: 118, // not real id 
    channel_secret: "6907", //edited it for security
    callback_url: "/m.html",
    scope: "openid profile",
    prompt: "consent",
    bot_prompt: "normal"
});

// here you set that all templates are located in `/views` directory
//app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

// here you set that you're using `ejs` template engine, and the
// default extension is `ejs`

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/index');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
    console.log(`server is listening to ${process.env.PORT || 5000}...`);
});

// Specify the path you want to start authorization.
app.use("/", login.auth());

// Specify the path you want to wait for the callback from LINE authorization endpoint.
app.use("/callbackurl", login.callback((req, res, next, token_response) => {
    // Success callback
    res.send(token_response);
},(req, res, next, error) => {
    // Failure callback
    res.status(400).json(error);
}));
```

Comment: what do you mean by - it does not output the res.send(token_response)?

Comment: is there a way where I can see the the token_response?

Comment: add `console.log(token_response)` just before res.send(token_response)?

Comment: Is there a way I can output it in callback url page?